# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for GoogleAuth: (?)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, google-authentication

i have this problem on running after compiling in the console.

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for GoogleAuth: (?)

this what i do with that in service that called googleServices.ts

```
// Core
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleAuth, User } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import { LoadingController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';

// Plugins
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';


@Injectable()
export class GoogleAuthServices {
  userImg;
  profile_picture;
  fullName;
  pushToken;
  status;

  constructor(
    public googleAuth: GoogleAuth, 
    public user: User, 
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, 
    public events: Events
  ) {}

  signIn(): Promise<any>{
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...'
    });

    return this.googleAuth.login().then((userRes)=>{
        loading.present();
        alert(JSON.stringify(userRes));
        loading.dismiss();
    });
  }
}
```

i search lot for solution.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add this to provider section that in app.module.ts file and everything works.

Answer (score -1):

May be a bug within @ionic/storage 1.1.7. To solve this, open your package.json and replace "@ionic/storage": "^1.1.7" with "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6".
Also don't forget to run npm install. That May resolve your problem.

Comment: For Futher You can visit this link: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-resolve-all-parameters-for-storage-make-sure-that-all-the-parameters-are-decorated-with-inject-or-have-valid-type-annotations-and-that-storage-is-decorated-with-injectable/47594/4

Comment: I have @ionic/storage 2.0.0.